# Finding specific points in UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uiview

Hey. I'm building an iPad app and I need to mark specific points on top of a map (UIImageView). I have the coordinates in inches, but I'm having trouble mapping the inch-based coords to iOS points, I've googled for hours and nothing too conclusive.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have actual units and want to convert those to points?

The iPad screen has a 9.7" diagonal. In points, it's 1024x768. So, applying Pythagoras, that's 1280 points on the diagonal. Therefore the points per inch is very close to 132, which I've also seen given elsewhere without computation from first principles.

So, a distance of x inches is x * 132 points. E.g. 1.5" is 198 points.

Comment: isn't 1024*768 the resolution in pixels? that gives the PPI, pixels per inch. I need to know how to find in cocoa points, whatever that unit of measure actually is.

Comment: A cocoa point is a pixel in this case. The OP is correct. So for iPad in Landscape you can near enough guarantee that the physical centre of the iPad is at (512,384).

Comment: What do you mean "in this case"? Everything I've read says that a point is not equals to a pixel. Anyhow, multiplying by 132 is not helping. The spot I want to mark is 1,28 inches in the x axis, and 2,05 on the y axis, and multiplying it by 132 is showing a completely different point.

Comment: I think "in this case" refers to the distinction between an iPhone 4 and other iPhone models; the former has twice as many pixels per point. If you go into Interface Builder, add a view that's 169 pixels by 271 pixels, run the app and measure the box, it'll be 1.28 by 2.05 inches.

Comment: I see, but I am on an iPad app. I can't believe there are no convenience methods to convert from real measure units to iOS measuring units.

Comment: On a non-retina device, 1 point = 1 pixel. There doesn't seem to be a method to get PPI (such that I've ever found), but it's 132 on the iPad, and somewhere around 163 on iPods and iPhones (iPod screens are fractionally smaller physically, but close enough). On retina devices (ie, just the iPhone 4 at present) 1 point = 2 pixels, which is the only reason I think Warren went with "in this case" — in case someone with an iPhone problem comes along and finds this question in the future and just to be precise generally.